# How to do an if-else condition in sql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

What I want to do is a select query and then if it is true set a variable of a table called 'afiliadospadron' to 1 but if it is false (it do not return anything) just set the variable to 0. My code isn't working. Can somebody help me please?

```
$query= "select nrodoc from oct20 where nrodoc = 05463xx union select nrodoc from dic20 where nrodoc = 054631xx";
$query2= "update afiliadospadron set condVotar = '1' where nroDoc = '5463xxx' ";
//$query3= "UPDATE afiliadospadron SET condVotar = 0 WHERE nroDoc = '5463xxx'";
if ($query) {
    $query2;
    } else {
        echo "next time";
//    $query3 = "UPDATE afiliadospadron SET condVotar = 0 WHERE nroDoc = '5463192'";;
    }
$statement = $conexion->prepare($query);
$statement = $conexion->prepare($query2);
//$statement = $conexion->prepare($query3);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: This can probably be done with a single query, but you'd have to further explain what you mean by query being true. If rows are found with that select? Also, you seem to have misconceptions about querying the database. Your `if` doesn't do anything and then you try to execute three queries at once after it. You can only prepare and execute one query at a time with a setup like this. And you'd have to execute the select first before evaluating its result.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
if ($result = $mysqli -> query($query)) {
  $query2;
  // Free result set
  $result -> free_result();
}
```

code from: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Answer (score 0):

The answer was

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

if ($result = $result ) {
    echo "yas";
    $statement = $conexion ->prepare($query2);
    $statement->execute();
    // Free result set
 
} else {
    echo "Wasnt found";
    $statement = $conexion ->prepare($query3);
    $statement->execute();
}
```